# Formula for angle bisector

Tags: geometry

I want to get from his formula:
$$L^2_c = ab - mn$$ to this $$L^2_c = ab - \dfrac{abc^2}{(a+b)^2}$$

[image]

The author has given this hint:
Use that $\dfrac{m}{n} = \dfrac{a}{b}$ and $m+n = c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sufficient to prove that
$$mn=\frac{abc^2}{(a+b)^2}$$

$\frac mn =\frac ab \Rightarrow m=\frac ab n$

$m+n=c \Rightarrow \frac ab n+n=c \Rightarrow n=\frac {c}{(\frac ab+1)}=\frac{bc}{a+b}$ and $m=\frac ab \cdot \frac{bc}{a+b}=\frac {ac}{(a+b)}$

Then $$mn= \frac {ac}{(a+b)} \cdot \frac{bc}{(a+b)}=\frac {abc^2}{(a+b)^2}$$